# Admin menu in different languages

Tags: menus, admin, language

My Wordpress admin language is partially in English and partially in Dutch. This causes some things (like events) to show in English on the site, which is not supposed to happen.

I used 'admin menu editor' and hid several items in the menu. It seems tat those items are the ones that are now not being translated to Dutch. I removed the plugin but nothing changed.

Hope anyone can help with getting the items to follow the setting of the WP language (Ducth)! I have no clue how to change the language of the event details otherwise.

Kind regards,
Jessica

[image: Menu items in English & Dutch]

[image: Half Dutch (date) half English]

Comment: Your plugins would need to have Dutch translations available. This won’t happen automatically. Someone needs to write them. If they don’t the  their text will likely be in English. If there aren’t any available you would need to do the translating yourself, which can be a complicated process, and would require the original plugin to be built to support translation. I suggest contacting the plugin developers.

Comment: But using basic Wordpress functionalities like showing calender items is seperate from a plugin right? I mentioned the admin menu editor plugin because that could be related to it, but I don't do any things specific with that plugin / nothing changes when I remove the plugin. In the screenshot I just added an event via Wordpress and everything is in English - both in the WP menu itself and in the output.

Comment: WordPress doesn’t have events functionality. That would be coming from a plugin. Or potentially your theme. Either way that theme/plugin needs to be translated.